# How do I enable Template Path and Block Name hints

Tags: template, design, template-hints

I am trying to find where in Magento's massively complex system, the templates are located and what blocks need to be modified.

I can use Chrome or Firefox web developer tools to see the code and easily test the modification, but when it comes down to actually making that change, I find myself wading through Magento's template directory and lost.

How do I find where the template is? How do I find the block name?

Answer (score 8):

Magento has a highlight mechanism in **System Configuration** to find the `template path` and also show you the `block name`.

Go down to the bottom of the left hand navigation and look for **Developer** and look for the **Debug** windowshade.

Go to the top left and change the scope till you have the options.

```
System Configuration => Developer => Debug
    Template Path Hints
    Add Block Names to Hints
```

[image]