# Magento 1.9.3.6 new customer account form not working

Tags: customer-account

I am also facing the same issues after upgrading the magento version from version 1.9.2 to version 1.9.3.6 ...pages simply show flas..
your help would be much appreciable.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is my Code for the registration:

```
<form action="https://www.my-example.com/customer/account/createpost/" method="post" id="form-validate">
        <div class="fieldset">
            <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="w5aGzmiwvqzKXllY">
            <h2 class="legend">Daten Ansprechpartner</h2>
            <ul class="form-list">
                <li class="fields">
```

In your code it is missing:

```
<form action="http://your-example.com/customer/account/createpost/?SID=91i3p974p1jtggdljian86v925" method="post" id="form-validate" class="register-form">
        <div class="fieldset">
            <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="">
            <h2 class="legend">Personal Information</h2>
            <ul class="form-list">
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="customer-name-middlename">
    <div class="field name-firstname">
```

I find the formkey for the login but not for registration. Try to find the right path for the .phtml with the simlinks.

Comment: i used this form key code  <div><input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" /></div>  in this path app/design/frontend/default/sm_macy/template/customer/form/register.phtml and app/design/frontend/default/sm_macy/template/customer/form/register.phtml  and app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml   but there is not result still the register pages just refresh only  .........any help would be much appreciable .........thanks

Comment: can you try to check with the magento debug. Like this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90117/how-do-i-enable-template-path-and-block-name-hints                                                             You can block all other if you put your IP in allowed IP's. Then you can see the path of the register.phtml maybe there is a another path couse there is only a formkey in your quick access on the register site.

Comment: I have added form key in this path as per you given instructions app/design/frontend/default/sm_macy/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml  but i dont know why it is not showing when i do inspect element .....

Comment: change fast the debug becouse it is open for all!!!! I can see the path and so on.

Comment: Please download the frontend/default/sm_macy/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml via ftp and make sure that the change have really occurred

Answer (score 1):

Have you editet the register.phtml formkey?
(In your custom template)
If it is so here is a way to solve the problem:
https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/Customer-Registration-not-working-in-1-9-2-2/td-p/20563

Comment: /app/design/frontend/default/sm_macy/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml

Comment: i edit the files in this code

Comment: /app/design/frontend/default/sm_macy/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml   but it not helps me ..

Comment: You have to edit this: 
1) app/design/frontend/[your_custom_theme]/template/customer/form/register.phtml
2) app/design/frontend/[your_custom_theme]/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
3) app/design/frontend/[your_custom_theme]/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
3) app/design/frontend/[your_custom_theme]/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml

Comment: i have edited as per given your links ....but still not result found  after edited the code i did the caches clears but nothing changes got effects....

Comment: It also possible that you must edit your cookie path and Domain in the configuration. In my config. for the path set a: / and for the domain set: www.youtdomain.com                                                                                      You can also test with an other browser.

Comment: yes .i just check in my admin and cookies also sets properly.......it is like www.youtdomain.com/ in the Session Cookie Management in the Web Area..........nothing happend

Comment: And with another Browser the same problem?

Comment: yes i checked in the other browser as well as private browser(Incognito).....not solutions

Comment: all edits for the form key are right? maybe check again. maybe give me the link to the shop.

Comment: here is the shop line http://inverterweldingmachine.com/customer/account/create/?SID=qf0kbciva6humdd54l75nlb1m4

Comment: plz fill the details and submit the form then you can understand easily .what actually the problems is ...

Comment: Hi Marcel 20, Could you help me for this problems............

Comment: I can look 21:00 MEZ.

Comment: Did you saw the websites link what i have shared with you........

Comment: yes i saw it. I think the form key is not on the right place. when i saw the html code from the registration site there is no form key in the code

Comment: @WasimAkram I saw your register site have still the problem. Have you check the the register.phtml

Comment: yes i check the register.phtml and i have added the form key which is this <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />  and once i update the pages then try to see the from after doing inspect element then it does not appear on the form ......need your more strong help...thanks

Comment: I will look for it. But you can See i Made a Account on yout website last week. I Put the formkey Manual in the html code and then IT works.

Comment: still the problems in not fixed ..plz help me ..its is very urgent