# magento website loads 2 images for a same product

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, frontend, optimization

i am working a magento website which is running on magento 1.9.2.2.

while working on its optimization, on tools pingdom i found a issue that page loads two images for a product i.e. small image and thumbnail image which ultimaltely leads to more http requests

can please anyone guide how do i let website to load 1 image per product.

screenshot attached.
[image]

Comment: Product view page? Product list page?

Comment: Product list page.

Comment: Check your theme's configuration, as this is probably some customization to show an alternative image or something like that

Comment: i checked the same and turned off the second image also refereshed the cache  but still this issue exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check which template in your project is being used for `catalog/product_list` blocks. Typically it would be...

> app/design/frontend/XXX/XXX/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

However, if you are using a customized theme (or maybe some extension) it would be surely overriden. You can validate all blocks & templates in all frontend pages using **Block Hint feature**: [How do I enable Template Path and Block Name hints](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90117/how-do-i-enable-template-path-and-block-name-hints)

Once you have located the template, you'd analyze the code & find where (and why) the duplicate image is being loaded. Remove or comment that code